# Create a dynamic array of JSON Object from values of multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need a little help creating a dynamic array of JSON object from the values of different elements. Example is elements below. I have other elements to create the values required for JSON. I didnt want to post 3 lots of same code. So belwo x3

```
 <tr>
      <td style="width: 5%"><label>Title:</label></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="leds" name="title" style="width:150px"value=""></td><tr>
      <td style="width: 5%"><label>Message:</label></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="leds" name="message" style="width: 150px" value=""></td><tr>
      <td style="width: 5%"><label>IP address:</label></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="leds" name="ip_address" style="width:150px" value=""></td>

     <td style="width: 5%"><label>Message Colour:</label></td>
     <td><select type="text" class="leds" name="led_colour" style="width:150px">
           <option value=""></option>
           <option value="255,0,0,0">Red</option>
           <option value="0,255,0,0">Green</option>
           <option value="0,0,255,0">Blue</option>
           <option value="255,165,0,0">Orange</option>
           <option value="255,255,0,0">Yellow</option>
           <option value="255,255,255,0">White</option>
           <option value="128,0,128,0">Purple</option>
           <option value="255,0,255,0">Fuchsia</option>
           <option value="192,192,192,0">Silver</option>
     </td>
   </tr>
```

I can get the values with the following

```
 $.each($('.leds'), function(index, obj) { 
console.log(index + ':' + obj.value); 

});
```

What I would like to do is create JSON like below:

```
 [{
"title": "Test1",
"message": "Test1 message",
"ip_address": "1.1.1.1",
"led_colour" : "255,0,0,0"},
{
"title": "Test2",
"message": "Test2 message",
"ip_address": "2.2.2.2",
"led_colour" : "255,0,0,0"},
{
"title": "Test3",
"message": "Test3 message",
"ip_address": "3.3.3.3",
"led_colour" : "255,0,0,0"
 }]
```

Comment: how look your `html` code? How many `td` in `tr`? I write code for two `td`... Becouse https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-buqh21DI-VJX4pELcmhuLqgtbWFv4Zv/view?usp=sharing

Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50892021/2661164

Answer (score 0):

I think it's solution, but better need modify your html structure

**1) In your case:**

```
function getJson(keys) {

    let result = [];

    $('.leds').each(function(i) {

        let keyIndex = i % keys.length,
            key = keys[keyIndex];

        if (!keyIndex) {
            result.push({});
        }

        let index = result.length - 1;
        result[index][key] = this.value;
    })

    return result;
}

const jsonData = getJson(['title', 'message', 'ip_address', 'led_colour']);

console.log('jsonData:', jsonData);
```

**2) Try use `tbody` for group your `tr`**

[DEMO in Codepen.io](https://codepen.io/slaawwa/pen/VdrLzQ)

```js
function getJson() {

    let result = [];

    $('tbody').each(function() {
        let item = {}
        $('.leds', this).each(function() {
            let $this = $(this);
            item[$this.prop('name')] = $this.val();
        })
        result.push(item);
    })
  
    console.log('result:', result)

    return result;
}

$(() => {

    getJson();

    $('button').click(() => {
        console.clear();
        const jsonData = getJson();
        alert(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Get Json Data</button>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 5%">
                <label>Title:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="title" style="width:150px" value="title1" class="leds"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 5%">
                <label>Message:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="message" style="width: 150px" value="mess1" class="leds"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 5%">
                <label>IP address:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="ip_address" style="width:150px" value="192.168.1.1" class="leds"/>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 5%">
                <label>Message Colour:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select type="text" name="led_colour" style="width:150px" class="leds">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="255,0,0,0" selected="selected">Red</option>
                    <option value="0,255,0,0">Green</option>
                    <option value="0,0,255,0">Blue</option>
                    <option value="255,165,0,0">Orange</option>
                    <option value="255,255,0,0">Yellow</option>
                    <option value="255,255,255,0">White</option>
                    <option value="128,0,128,0">Purple</option>
                    <option value="255,0,255,0">Fuchsia</option>
                    <option value="192,192,192,0">Silver</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 5%">
                <label>Title:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="title" style="width:150px" value="title2" class="leds"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 5%">
                <label>Message:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="message" style="width: 150px" value="mess2" class="leds"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 5%">
                <label>IP address:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="ip_address" style="width:150px" value="192.168.1.2" class="leds"/>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 5%">
                <label>Message Colour:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select type="text" name="led_colour" style="width:150px" class="leds">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="255,0,0,0" selected="selected">Red</option>
                    <option value="0,255,0,0">Green</option>
                    <option value="0,0,255,0">Blue</option>
                    <option value="255,165,0,0">Orange</option>
                    <option value="255,255,0,0">Yellow</option>
                    <option value="255,255,255,0">White</option>
                    <option value="128,0,128,0">Purple</option>
                    <option value="255,0,255,0">Fuchsia</option>
                    <option value="192,192,192,0">Silver</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 5%">
                <label>Title:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="title" style="width:150px" value="title3" class="leds"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 5%">
                <label>Message:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="message" style="width: 150px" value="mess3" class="leds"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 5%">
                <label>IP address:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="ip_address" style="width:150px" value="192.168.1.3" class="leds"/>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 5%">
                <label>Message Colour:</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select type="text" name="led_colour" style="width:150px" class="leds">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="255,0,0,0" selected="selected">Red</option>
                    <option value="0,255,0,0">Green</option>
                    <option value="0,0,255,0">Blue</option>
                    <option value="255,165,0,0">Orange</option>
                    <option value="255,255,0,0">Yellow</option>
                    <option value="255,255,255,0">White</option>
                    <option value="128,0,128,0">Purple</option>
                    <option value="255,0,255,0">Fuchsia</option>
                    <option value="192,192,192,0">Silver</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks @Slaawwa. This worked perfect. Once I stringified the jsonData  I got the expected results. I tried to upvote but Im not at that level yet

Comment: @sqlNoob, you are wellcome!

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to loop each tr and get all .leds inputs, get the name of input and it's value an build object, then put it to array. See the code bellow.

```
var itemsArray = [];
$.each($('tr'), function() { 
   var item = {};
   $(this).find('.leds').each(function(index, obj) {
       item[$(obj).attr("name")]=$(obj).val();

    });
    itemsArray.push(item);
});
```

Comment: Thansk for your reply. Response below gave me exactly what I needed